# Passing a from through Echo function

Tags: php, html, echo

I have to make an if statement to place a form in my page if the user is an admin, but I'm having trouble with the syntax. Right now it is like this:

```
    if($_SESSION['tipo'] == "admin")
                {
                    echo '<form method=\'POST\' action=\'adicionaproduto.php\'>
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Adicionar Produto\" name=\"adicionaproduto\">
                    </form>'
                }
```

It is not working and I think it's a mater of using `""` or `'`.

Comment: Don't escape the double quotes. You only escape the quotes being used by PHP for encapsulating the string's data. Oh and you missed a closing `;` after the echo..

Comment: had you bothered checking for errors with error reporting, it would have told you about the syntax error `</form>'` see what's missing? Visit this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply it to your code and make sure you started the session.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if($_SESSION['tipo'] == "admin")
             { ?>
                  <form method='POST' action='adicionaproduto.php'>
                  <input type="submit" value="Adicionar Produto" name="adicionaproduto">
                   </form>
           <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: why should they *"Try this"*? why not point out where the real problem is?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['tipo'] == "admin"){
  echo '
        <form method="POST" action="adicionaproduto.php">
         <input type="submit" value="Adicionar Produto" name="adicionaproduto">
        </form>';
}
```

This should get you started
i echoed using single quotes and the used double quotes all through afterwards in order to avoid escaping strings. This is good practise for echoing html in php

Comment: ok and the errors were made where exactly? what did you change so future readers to the question know what you did here.

Comment: Don't escape the double quotes. You only escape the quotes being used by PHP for encapsulating the string's data.

Comment: don't tell me that, put it in your answer.

Comment: i echoed using single quotes so i can do away with character escaping and the used double quotes all through.